# Объединить строки в результата запроса

Tags: sql, sqlite

У меня есть запрос

```
SELECT UE._id, UE.fName, UE.lName, UE.birthday, UE.age, UE.avatarUrl, SE.name  
FROM ( SELECT * 
       FROM UserEntity 
       WHERE _id = :userId) as UE, 
     ( SELECT name 
       FROM SpecialtyEntity 
       INNER JOIN UserWithSpecialty on SpecialtyEntity.specialtyId = UserWithSpecialty.specialtyId 
                                   AND UserWithSpecialty.userId = :userId) as SE
```

он возвращает следущие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне объеденить эти двестроки в одну, что б колонка `name` выводилась через запятую `name=Менеджер, Разработчик`

Comment: Добавить GROUP BY и GROUP_CONCAT().

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UE._id, UE.fName, UE.lName, UE.birthday, UE.age, UE.avatarUrl, group_concat(SE.name)
FROM ( SELECT * 
       FROM UserEntity 
       WHERE _id = :userId) as UE, 
     ( SELECT name 
       FROM SpecialtyEntity 
       INNER JOIN UserWithSpecialty on SpecialtyEntity.specialtyId = UserWithSpecialty.specialtyId 
                                   AND UserWithSpecialty.userId = :userId) as SE group by UE._id
```

Comment: `group by` не помогает, ни по какому из полей

Comment: Там еще group_concat, не забыли ее?